# How can I permenantly change language on Open Office?

Tags: openoffice

I download Open Office and found `ooo_albanian_dict_1.6.2.oxt` (the language I need to use).

Now though, every time I want to write in Albanian I have to change this setting

[image]

I tried going to **Preferences > Language Settings** and in `default languages for documents` Albanian is not there

It's anoying to have to make these changes every time I use Open Office.

Comment: Welcome , the [official documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Adding_More_Languages) explain how to add more languages.

Comment: @GAD3R thanks, I read that but it seems outdated!! this `Tools > Options > Language Settings > Writing Aids` nor this `File > Wizards > Install new dictionaries` exist, and **preferences language settings** my language doesn't exist. I downloaded this: http://shkenca.org/index.php/informatike/43-softuere/26-drejtshkrimi-me-openoffice-org-3-x and, like I said, only works if I do it manually everytime